# yield multiple item from one page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to yield multiple items from one page. Items differ by one field. I collect one item, then create new items in a loop, i.e.:

```py
for i in new_fields:
    new_item = item
    new_item["new_field"] = i
    yield new_item
```

But scrapy just returns me n of same rows, where n is a len(new_fields).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please provide more of your code and clarify what you expect should be happening and what is actually happenning

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Item Loaders in this case. You can read more about it on the documentation page https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html.
In general, it would look something like this:

```
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from myproject.items import Product

def parse(self, response):
    for i in new_fields:
        l = ItemLoader(item=Product(), response=response)
        #  you can add data using CSS, XPath or values
        l.add_xpath('name', '//div[@class="product_name"]')
        l.add_css('stock', 'p#stock')
        l.add_value('last_updated', 'today')
        yield l.load_item()
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is, that the statement `new_item = item`
does not create a copy of item. `newitem` will merely be a reference to item, so when you are updating `newitem["new_field"]`, you are also updating `item["new_field"]`.

In consequence, the item that is yielded is always the same, however, it will have a different state each time it is yielded. As such, the following code should print the different values for new_field:

```
for item in sub_that_yields():
    print(item["new_field"])
```

On the other side, the below code will only print one value:

```py
new_items = list(sub_that_yields())
for item in new_items:
    print(item["new_field"])
```

In the second example, `new_items` will be a list of n instances of the same item (as the sub always yields the same item as explained before). So with each update that is done to this item, all items in the list change.

The easiest way to fix this is to make new_item a real copy of item. How this works depends on what item is, it could be as simple as just writing `new_item = item.copy()` or it might require using `copy` or `deepcopy` from python's `copy` module.

Comment: You may want to expand on your answer and explain your code, to make sure everyone having the same issue as OP understands the solution.